# Tracking errors back to github pull requests

Tags: github, pull-request

We are hosting a c/c++ based repo with multiple branches in Github , while doing CI , there are usually on the average 10 pull requests in each integration build , and if something fails , we have to track it in all of the merged PRs to figure out which one did the mess , i want to work it programaticaly so that i can know which pull requests fails the build. What can be the best approach to work on this problem.

One thing that i forgot to mention is that each PR is individually build and tested already before the merge into feature branch.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to change your process a bit and only allow merging of Pull Requests that:

1. Build without errors (including running integration tests)
2. Are rebased to fit on the tip of your master branch (fast forward commits only)

Since the branch build without errors, and it was rebased on the latest master, merging it will never break master.  Unrebased branches that are seemingly without conflicts can still break things if changes in not directly related files conflict with each other as the conflict algorithm is pretty simplistic.

Lacking that, git also has an option that can be used during an interactive rebase to run a command (the `exec` option) after each rebase step.  In other words, you could rewind your branch back to a known working state, and then let git apply each commit in turn and run a command that checks if everything passes your tests with the `exec` option.

In this way you can automatically discover which commit broke your tests.